How do I make my navigation icon appear in mobile mode for a ReactJS and TailwindCSS app
I'll appreciate help with my bug.
I have a ReactJS and TailwindCSS application. The navigation displays fine in desktop mode but in mobile mode, the navigation or hamburger icon doesn't appear.
My App.jsx file is in the path: travelworld/src/component/Navbar.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { FaTimes, FaBars } from 'react-icons/fa'

const Navbar = () => {
    const [showNavigationForMobile, setShowNavigationForMobile] = useState(false);
    return (
        <nav className='fixed m-4 top-0 right-0 left-0 shadow-lg z-50 bg-white'>
            <div className='container px-4 flex justify-between items-center h-16'>
                <h3 className='text-2xl font-bold'>Travel</h3>
                {!showNavigationForMobile && (
                <div className='md:show flex space-x-4 text-sm font-bold items-center'>
                    <Link to="/" className='px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white'>Home</Link>
                    <Link to="/gallery" className='px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white'>Gallery</Link>
                    <Link to="/contact" className='px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white'>Contact</Link>
                    <Link to="/about" className='px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white'>About</Link>
                    <button className='py-2 px-6 border bg-gray-400'>Login</button>
                </div>
                )}
                <div className='md:hidden'>
                    <button onClick={() => setShowNavigationForMobile(!showNavigationForMobile)}>
                    {showNavigationForMobile ? <FaTimes /> : <FaBars />}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            {showNavigationForMobile && (
            <div className='flex space-y-6 py-4 flex-col bg-white items-center'>
                <Link to="/" className='px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white'>Home</Link>
                <Link to="/gallery" className='px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white'>Gallery</Link>
                <Link to="/contact" className='px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white'>Contact</Link>
                <Link to="/about" className='px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white'>About</Link>
                <button className='py-2 px-6 border bg-gray-300'>Login</button>
            </div>
            )}
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar

My Home.jsx file is in the path: travelworld/src/pages/Home.jsx
import React from "react";
import PopularDestination from '../component/PopularDestination';
import Services from '../component/Services';
import Clients from '../component/Clients';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className='relative h-screen bg-cover bg-center' style={{backgroundImage : "url('/images/hotel_paris.jpg')"}}>
                <div className='absolute inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 flex flex-col items-center justify-center'>
                    <h1 className='text-4xl md:text-6xl font-bold text-white mb-4'>Explore the world with us</h1>
                    <p className='text-lg md:text-2xl text-white mb-8'>Discover amazing places at exclusive deals</p>
                    <button className='border text-white px-6 py-2 rounded-full text-lg md:text-xl hover:bg-blue-500 transform transition duration-300 hover:scale-105'>Get started</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <PopularDestination />
            <Services />
            <Clients />
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;

My App.jsx file is in the path: travelworld/src/App.jsx
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Navbar from "./component/Navbar";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;

My package.json file is in the path: travelworld/package.json
{
  "name": "travelworld",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-icons": "^5.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.8.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
    "eslint": "^9.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.9",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.41",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.9",
    "vite": "^5.4.0"
  }
}


I have just reproduced your code on my end and I found where your bug is lurking. The bug is in the div that has md:show. That class name isn't a valid Tailwind class. Also, you're not hiding that navigation on mobile screen breakpoint. Tailwind is mobile-first, so the flex class is going to propagate to all the breakpoints considering the md:show class isn't valid. I have made adjustment to your code and this should fix your issue:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FaTimes, FaBars } from "react-icons/fa";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [showNavigationForMobile, setShowNavigationForMobile] = useState(false);
  return (
    <nav className="fixed m-4 top-0 right-0 left-0 shadow-lg z-50 bg-white">
      <div className="container px-4 flex justify-between items-center h-16">
        <h3 className="text-2xl font-bold">Travel</h3>
        {!showNavigationForMobile && (
          <div className="hidden md:flex space-x-4 text-sm font-bold items-center">
            <Link
              to="/"
              className="px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white"
            >
              Home
            </Link>
            <Link
              to="/gallery"
              className="px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white"
            >
              Gallery
            </Link>
            <Link
              to="/contact"
              className="px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white"
            >
              Contact
            </Link>
            <Link
              to="/about"
              className="px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white"
            >
              About
            </Link>
            <button className="py-2 px-6 border bg-gray-400">Login</button>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="md:hidden">
          <button
            onClick={() => setShowNavigationForMobile(!showNavigationForMobile)}
          >
            {showNavigationForMobile ? <FaTimes /> : <FaBars />}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      {showNavigationForMobile && (
        <div className="flex space-y-6 py-4 flex-col bg-white items-center">
          <Link to="/" className="px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white">
            Home
          </Link>
          <Link
            to="/gallery"
            className="px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white"
          >
            Gallery
          </Link>
          <Link
            to="/contact"
            className="px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white"
          >
            Contact
          </Link>
          <Link
            to="/about"
            className="px-6 py-2 hover:bg-gray-600 hover:text-white"
          >
            About
          </Link>
          <button className="py-2 px-6 border bg-gray-300">Login</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;



Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate the time you took to copy the code, test it and provide a concise solution. Your explanation was very helpful and easy to follow. I've implemented your solution and it's working perfectly. Your contribution to the community is valued and appreciated. Thanks again for your expertise and kindness!

I'm glad I was able to help. You can as well mark the answer as correct so others who run into similar issue can quickly implement similar solution.
